# Jsf on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf-2

Though ive done everything like in this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-jsf-2-example/

Somtimes when i refresh/load view it throws exception, which only occurs when i run it locally

```
WARNING: /javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Wed, 12 Dec 2012 10:32:00 GMT
    at org.mortbay.io.BufferUtil.toLong(BufferUtil.java:106)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields$Field.getLongValue(HttpFields.java:1479)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields.getLongField(HttpFields.java:720)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Request.getIntHeader(Request.java:728)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getIntHeader(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:106)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter$RequestWrapper.getDateHeader(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:405)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceImpl.getIfModifiedHeader(ResourceImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceImpl.userAgentNeedsUpdate(ResourceImpl.java:347)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:255)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:125)
    at org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:85)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:591)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:383)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

**web.xml**

```
<xml>

    <display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>



    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/hello.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value/>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**welcome.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>GAE + JSF</title>
</h:head>
<h:body bgcolor="white">

    <h1>Google App Engine + JSF 2.0 example - welcome.xhtml</h1>


</h:body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is a bug in `com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter$RequestWrapper.getDateHeader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a know issue since GAE SDK 1.7.2

Take a look here and *star* it to be updated upon possible updates regarding the issue...

[Issue 8420:    java.lang.NumberFormatException Thrown for Files Managed by JSF 2.0 Resource Management Framework](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8420)

You can try using SDK prior to 1.7.2

---

**Edit**

Look for possible fix in here : [Issue 8415:    Parsing date header as int caused NumberFormatException](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8415)