# NumberFormatException throw out from BufferUtil.java when run in GAE1.7.3+

Tags: google-app-engine, richfaces

I'm using richface 4.3.0.M2 and it's throwing the exception below when I run with GAE 1.7.3 and GAE 1.7.4.  However, it works fine with GAE 1.7.2.

Any help or workarounds available?

```
INFO: request=com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter$RequestWrapper@14e834c, response=com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter$ResponseWrapper@18e2fc5, chain=Faces Servlet
14/12/2012 2:01:35 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: /javax.faces.resource/application.css.jsf
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Wed, 05 Dec 2012 23:22:19 GMT
    at org.mortbay.io.BufferUtil.toLong(BufferUtil.java:106)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields$Field.getLongValue(HttpFields.java:1479)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields.getLongField(HttpFields.java:720)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Request.getIntHeader(Request.java:728)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getIntHeader(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:106)
    at
```

Comment: At the moment the latest GAE version is 1.7.4. Why do you use 1.3?

Comment: @PeterKnego I have the same problem and I use GAE version 1.7.4.

Comment: To add my info, I use GAE version 1.7.4, primefaces 3.4 (not richfaces).  Sometimes I receive this error for jQuery.js.jsf while other times I'll receive it on theme.css.jsf, so I can't help but think this is due to bad redirection of some sort.  The error is always a NumberFormatException on today's date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that it's a pending problem with google app engine.  [The issue page can be found here.](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8415)  They offer a workaround which does fix this problem, though it has not yet been fixed formally.

[Similar question made here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838811/jsf-on-google-app-engine)