# java.lang.NumberFormatException at org.mortbay.io.BufferUtil.toLong(BufferUtil.java:106)

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf, jetty

I have a problem running jsf + primeface on app engine. Specifically I have:

primefaces 3.4.1 
jsf 2.1.7
appengine sdk 1.8.9
Java 7

I get the following exception on every page I load. However if I refresh the page it loads normally. I started having this issue only when I migrated to appengine 1.8.9. Previously I was using 1.6.6 and everything was running smoothly.

I searched around and it seems that this is a common issue. However I couldn t find any solution. Anybody has an idea about that? Thank you

```
WARNING: /javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Wed, 22 Jan 2014 08:35:40 GMT
    at org.mortbay.io.BufferUtil.toLong(BufferUtil.java:106)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields$Field.getLongValue(HttpFields.java:1479)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields.getLongField(HttpFields.java:720)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Request.getIntHeader(Request.java:728)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getIntHeader(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:106)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter$RequestWrapper.getDateHeader(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:405)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceImpl.getIfModifiedHeader(ResourceImpl.java:368)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceImpl.userAgentNeedsUpdate(ResourceImpl.java:345)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:255)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:125)
    at org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:91)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:591)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: take a look at my answer over here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13840191/617373

Answer (score 0):

Number conversion software varies in how lenient or strict to be about number formats.  The one in [BufferUtil](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/jetty-6.1.9/modules/jetty/src/main/java/org/mortbay/io/BufferUtil.java.shtml) looks rigid and quite strict.

Try logging or outputting the String you wish to convert, between some delimiters, and look for other suspicious characters that may have crept into your String as a result of the software upgrade.  Even a '+' or a trailing space can spoil the party.

Comment: Thank you Martin. However, I am not converting any String...at least deliberately. I just want to load a jsf page.
The funny thing is that if i refresh the page then it loads as expected.

Comment: I'm glad it works.  The reason can be found by looking about 9 lines down the stack trace where getIfModifiedHeader() is called.  The BufferUtil.toLong() method threw an exception trying to parse an incomplete Modified date or time from the browser's HTTP request header.  When you refreshed, the browser generated a fresh header that BufferUtil.toLong() could parse.  Problem solved :-)